# Wordpress - Como retirar pagina do search.php e procurar somente posts?

Tags: wordpress

minha página do search.php do wordpress está mostrando as postagens e páginas criadas, como faço para mostrar somente as postagens?

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

   <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'cf' ); ?> role="article">

     <header class="entry-header article-header">
       CONSTRUÇÃO DO BLOCO
     </header>

   </article>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala amigo, tudo beleza?

É bem fácil! Basta você adicionar este código abaixo na functions.php do seu tema, que as páginas já não serão mais exibidas nas pesquisas.

```
if (!is_admin()) {
function wpb_search_filter($query) {
   if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', 'post');
   }
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpb_search_filter');
}
```

Comment: Vlw esse funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a documentação da função get_posts:

[get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts)

```
<?php $args = array('post_type' => 'post');
    $posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>
```

Comment: Chegou a funcionar, mas com isso a paginação do site para de funcionar.

Comment: Verdade, @kaiquemix. Aqui nesse post sugerem fazer a mesma coisa que o colega de cima, mas com mais detalhes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838864/how-do-i-get-pagination-to-work-for-get-posts-in-wordpress